# Transposing Pandas dataframe on multi-indexed data

Tags: pandas

This is the data with which I'm working

[image]

And I'm trying to get something like the following:

[image]

The documentation speaks of transposition, but I'm lost with how this would be applied to multi-indexed data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the first six columns are the multi-index, you need not a transpose, but an unstack:

```
df1 = df.unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
#                                      Count        
#Parliamentarian: Vote                     1    2  3
#Parliament Session Sitting Vote Party              
#42         1       164     255  BQ        7    0  0
#                                C         0   81  0
#                                Lib     162    0  1
#                                NDP       0   34  1
#                           256  BQ       10    0  0
#                                C        81    0  0
#                                Lib       0  164  1
#                                NDP      34    0  1
```

You can add the fourth column, if you wish:

```
df1['Count',4] = 0
```